# jwplayer, can I have 'watched' tag on watched videos in playlist?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, jwplayer

I run a jwplayer playlist. When the user in my website has watched some videos from that playlist, can I have a label or tag placed on those watched videos? The label should have the word: 'watched'. The same idea is on Youtube.
Any help, please.

Comment: We don't really have a tagging feature I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm looking for similar functionality. An alternative thought is to add the word 'watched' next to the title by setting with  **playlist[].title** [link](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference#playlist)

Comment: Possibly, have you tried that?

Comment: Hi Ethan, yes I did. It's not the ideal, but it works. The only thing is that stayed better in the **playlist[].description** option, as showed in the red highlight line: ![Image](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=12140603035812).